# Error in adding to 2d array or looping through 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a problem in this code:

```
while ($end <= $to){
        $currentDates = array("from" => $start, "to"=>$end);
        $allDates[] = $currentDates;
        echo 'from: ', $currentDates["from"]->format("m-d-y"),'<br>';
        unset($currentDates);
        $start->add($intervalObj);
        $end->add($intervalObj);
    }

var_dump($allDates);
```

the echo in the loop shows the correct values but vardump shows the last dates to be added to the array in all the positions of the array

Comment: Can i ask what is the purpose of the loop ?? Are you trying to extract dates of a given range

Comment: It's a function the takes a start and end DateTime objects and interval type and interval amount and returns an array of DateTime objects based on those criteria.

Comment: what you get if var_dump($allDates) before foreach ?

Comment: good idea. I get the same thing I get in the foreach loop. So the problem is in the while loop.

Comment: When I say I get the same thing I mean the array is full of the same date repeated over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need 2 loops for that  ....

The error is from your loop

```
while ($end <= $to){
                ^-------  This was never used
```

Also See

```
$currentDates = array("from" => $start, "to"=>$end);
         Not in the Condition  --^              ^---- To means something else
```

You while can be as simple as

```
$start = new DateTime("2012-4-12");
$end = new DateTime("2012-12-12");
$dv = new DateInterval('P24D'); // Every 24 days

echo "<pre>";
while ( $start <= $end ) {
    echo "From ", $start->format('Y-m-d');
    $start->add($dv);
    echo " To ", $start->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
From 2012-04-12 To 2012-05-06
From 2012-05-06 To 2012-05-30
From 2012-05-30 To 2012-06-23
From 2012-06-23 To 2012-07-17
From 2012-07-17 To 2012-08-10
From 2012-08-10 To 2012-09-03
From 2012-09-03 To 2012-09-27
From 2012-09-27 To 2012-10-21
From 2012-10-21 To 2012-11-14
From 2012-11-14 To 2012-12-08
From 2012-12-08 To 2013-01-01
```

Comment: The echo's are just for debugging the problem. The $to is used earlier in the function. This function takes in a start date end date interval type and an interval amount and returns an array of DateTime objects based on the supplied information. The echo in the while loop shows the correct dates but when I dump the $allDates array it shows the last date added for all positions in the array.

Comment: Ok which this can you see what you did wrong ??  or you still need  help @Casey

Comment: @Baba I edited the question to, I hope, more clearly explain the problem.