# All values are being overwritten when adding to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deep copy a DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579458/how-do-i-deep-copy-a-datetime-object)
>   [Error in adding to 2d array or looping through 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900097/error-in-adding-to-2d-array-or-looping-through-2d-array)

So my code is:

```
    while ($end <= $to){
        $currentDates = array("from" => $start, "to"=>$end);
        $allDates[] = $currentDates;
        echo '<br>', var_dump($allDates);
        unset($currentDates);
        $start->add($intervalObj);
        $end->add($intervalObj);
    }
```

But every time $currentDates is added to $allDates it adds a position to $allDates like I expect but it also overwrites all the previous array positions with the current values of $currentDates.

This is the result of the var_dump in the loop

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["from"]=> object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-10 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } ["to"]=> object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-11 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } } } 

array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["from"]=> object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-11 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } ["to"]=> object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-12 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["from"]=> object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-11 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } ["to"]=> object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-12 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } } } 

array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["from"]=> object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-12 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } ["to"]=> object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-13 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["from"]=> object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-12 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } ["to"]=> object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-13 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } } [2]=> array(2) { ["from"]=> object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-12 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } ["to"]=> object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-13 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" } } }
```

Comment: What did you not add your function function in the other question instead of creating a new one ??? .

Comment: because it basically turned into a different question. The original title to the question was asking about the foreach which wasn't part of this question. The original question had some echo statements that confused what I was trying to do. Also if someone runs into this problem in the future this question (and this answer, thanks AndreKR) are much more likely to solve their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$start` and `$end` are objects, which are always assigned by reference. You need to create new, distinct objects. See [How do I deep copy a DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579458/how-do-i-deep-copy-a-datetime-object) on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I could have starred at that code for a year and it wouldn't have occurred to me that they were being assigned by reference.